# How is it possible the verb "mean" be intransitive in "How do you mean?"?

Tags: intransitive

It's explained [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269711/how-do-you-mean-vs-what-do-you-mean) what "*How do you mean?*" means. But I can't understand how it's possible the verb "*mean*" be intransitive in this sentence. Dictionaries don't give any its intransitive meaning which would be appropriate here. Maybe there's just an ellipsis and the whole sentence is "*How do you mean **it**?*"?

Comment: How do you mean [what you just said]?

Comment: It's highly informal, not really grammatical.

Comment: @BillJ I'm sorry for being meticulous but what does "not really grammatical" mean? I can only understand "grammatical" or "not grammatical" but "not REALLY grammatical"... It leads me into a stupor.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "how do you mean" is very unlikely to be uttered by a native speaker. This is because "mean" is not use used in an intrasitive sence with a adjective complement that could be queried with "how".

On the other hand "what do you mean?" is a normal question.

"How do you mean" is an ungrammatical utterance.